# whislist only show one item on Magento 1.7 and 1.8 too

Tags: wishlist

I am currently using one theme on 1 website and 4 store views. `My issue is Wishlist only shows one item every time.`

I found a possible solution in this:
`posthttp://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/291225/,` but you have to modify the Core, which is not a good idea.

I had read in any website, which after the upgrade to version 1.8 Magento, could fix but so far nothing. I tested this on several themes that I have installed with same results.

Where could be the problem for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You posted a probable solution and everyone would agree that you should not modify the core. However, you could try whether what is suggested in the thread and see whether it works afterwards. Then, describe here, what you did and how it works or does not work and someone might be able to give you hints on how to solve this more elegantly!

Comment: I had this issue before and it was because of the theme I had. In the wishlist page it also displayed on the left sidebar the "last added product" to the wishlist. and because the way it was constructed when calling `_getWishlist` I would get the wishlist object as a singleton. So the same object on the left sidebar and center. And since a limit of 1 was applied to the sidebar block, the same limit was applied to the content also. Check if this is not the case for you. Just to get it out of the way.